# Pine Script how to detect close lower than line(not other bar close)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Im not coder, just tryna solve my problem by myself

I need this thing to detect candle closing lower than one line and higher than other

#### So there is my code right now:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeThecolor.blue

//@version=4
study("EthStrategy1h15m", overlay =true)
lb = input(5, title="Left Bars", minval = 1)
rb = input(5, title="Right Bars", minval = 1)
showsupres = input(true, title="Support/Resistance", inline = "srcol")
supcol = input(color.lime, title ="", inline = "srcol")
rescol = input(color.red, title ="", inline = "srcol")
srlinestyle = input(line.style_solid, title = "Line Style/Width", inline ="style")
srlinewidth = input(1, title = "", minval = 1, maxval = 5, inline ="style")

ph = pivothigh(lb, rb)
pl = pivotlow(lb, rb)

hl = iff(ph, 1, iff(pl, -1, na)) // Trend direction
zz = iff(ph, ph, iff(pl, pl, na)) // similar to zigzag but may have multiple highs/lows
zz :=iff(pl and hl == -1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == -1 and pl > valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, zz)
zz :=iff(ph and hl == 1  and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1) == 1  and ph < valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, zz)

hl := iff(hl==-1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)==1 and zz > valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, hl)
hl := iff(hl==1 and valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)==-1 and zz < valuewhen(zz, zz, 1), na, hl)
zz := iff(na(hl), na, zz)

findprevious()=>  // finds previous three points (b, c, d, e)
    ehl = iff(hl==1, -1, 1)
    loc1 = 0.0, loc2 = 0.0, loc3 = 0.0, loc4 = 0.0
    xx = 0
    for x=1 to 1000
        if hl[x]==ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc1 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x=xx to 1000
        if hl[x]==ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc2 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := iff(hl==1, -1, 1)
    for x=xx to 1000
        if hl[x]==ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc3 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x=xx to 1000
        if hl[x]==ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc4 := zz[x]
            break
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4]

float a = na, float b = na, float c = na, float d = na, float e = na
if not na(hl)
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()
    a := zz 
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4

_hh = zz and (a > b and a > c and c > b and c > d)
_ll = zz and (a < b and a < c and c < b and c < d)
_hl = zz and ((a >= c and (b > c and b > d and d > c and d > e)) or (a < b and a > c and b < d))
_lh = zz and ((a <= c and (b < c and b < d and d < c and d < e)) or (a > b and a < c and b > d))

float res = na, float sup = na
res := iff(_lh, zz, res[1])
sup := iff(_hl, zz, sup[1])

int trend = na
trend := iff(close > res, 1, iff(close < sup, -1, nz(trend[1])))

res := iff((trend == 1 and _hh) or (trend == -1 and _lh), zz, res)
sup := iff((trend == 1 and _hl) or (trend == -1 and _ll), zz, sup)
rechange = res != res[1]
suchange = sup != sup[1]

var line resline = na
var line supline = na
if showsupres
    if rechange
        line.set_x2(resline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(resline, extend = extend.right)
        resline := line.new(x1 = bar_index - rb, y1 = res, x2 = bar_index, y2 = res, color = rescol, extend = extend.right, style = srlinestyle, width = srlinewidth)
     
    if suchange
        line.set_x2(supline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(supline, extend = extend.right)
        supline := line.new(x1 = bar_index - rb, y1 = sup, x2 = bar_index, y2 = sup, color = supcol, extend = extend.right, style = srlinestyle, width = srlinewidth)    

lowerOrSameClose = barstate.isconfirmed and (close <= close[1])
plotshape(series=lowerOrSameClose, style=shape.diamond, color = color.red)
```

#### I need to place "supline" instead of "close[1]" (end of the code) and repeat the same thing with "Higher or same close than resline", how do I properly do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just edited, I guess something wrong gone while I pasted the code. It works for me.
As the result I'm looking for pattern where line ends when the candle closes higher or lower than it (body, not shadow) so I want to detect closing price and connect it with line.delete

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do what your are looking for, you must record each line id, line color and line value in a matrix.
Each new bar, you will have to seach for lines in your matrix to delete.
And then (after deleting all lines on your chart), you will have to draw all the lines again on your chart with the informations from your matrix.